# PHP Imagepng output does not shown in any browser

Tags: php, html, gd

I have this php script which is supposed to return a png image in the brower.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$img=imagecreatefrompng($myimagepath);
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

But any of my browser (Firefox, IE or Google) can't displayed the result

I want to know how to solve this problem ?
I use Wampserver 2.4

Thank you

Comment: There should not be anything in output before `header(...)`. To avoid, use `ob_clean()` before the 1st `header(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script itself seems to be OK. I see two possible problems:

1. `$myimagepath` is corrupt or inaccessible
2. **PNG Support** is not enabled. check it with `phpinfo()`, it should be under `gd`.

Comment: Double checked the script and tested it. Works fine. On my machine PNG support is enabled. We will have to wait for the OP to check his server or the image path.

Comment: i checked phpinfo() and gd work well. i have the 2.4.10 version.

Comment: How can i check to see if the file is corrupted ?

Comment: @OnésiphoreKonanKouamé and `PNG Support` under `gd`?

Comment: i checked png support is enabled

Comment: @OnésiphoreKonanKouamé So, check the image path. Hardcode `$myimagepath` and put there a URL like https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png. Still image isn't displayed?

Comment: I uploaded google logo in my ftp folder and test it now my browser display a random of symbol undreadable something like that �PNG  IHDRR^�{.U IDATx���k�%�u&��ȼ�nu�Q-�R�dK,��nYc

Comment: Good. Now uncomment (remove `//`) from the header. What do you see?

Comment: Yes now remove those ```//``` before ```header('...``` and you're good to go.

Comment: i have now a small image

Comment: Great. From now on, just make sure `$myimagepath` leads to real image path! URL or local, it doesn't matter.

Comment: i changed the $myimagepath to the real image, now i have a small rectangle like an image and when i open the source code of the page displayed in my browser. i have this code <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost:8080/myfirstapp/"> is it normal @NadavS.

Comment: Yes. Regarding the size - it depends on your image, put a large image and it'll be large...

Comment: I'm running into something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820434/my-php-cannot-create-a-true-color-image

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, but there might be an error.

Replace

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

for troubleshooting and refresh page in browser.

Maybe there is any error messages?

Comment: Exactly the opposite... Commenting this line will prevent the image from being displayed

Comment: Yes. Browser will show content of a page like a text. Maybe there are an error?

Comment: @NadavS. We are aware of that, but If there is an error the image will be corrupt and the browser can't display it. So we want the default content type, which is text/html to see the error. I have an edit pending on this answer to make it clearer what Pavel is trying to say.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard You're right. but that's not a final solution.

Comment: when i comment header('content-type: image/png'), there is nothing but if i use header('content-type: image/png') with imagepng($img,"myimage.png"); i have the same image in my ftp folder.

Comment: Please move a copy of that image to a folder accessible with your browser and try to view it in the browser.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard i can open the image with my browser

Answer (score 1):

I assume the following should work for you:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($myimagepath);
```

This doesn't rely on `gd` being installed.

If this does work, something is wrong with `gd`.

If this does not work, something is wrong with the picture.

Comment: I uploaded google logo in my ftp folder and test it now my browser display a random of symbol undreadable something like that �PNG  IHDRR^�{.U IDATx���k�%�u&��ȼ�nu�Q-�R�dK,��nYc

Comment: That is your browser interpreting the png file as ```text/html```. Make sure you have the line ```header('Content-Type: image/png')``` without slashes in front.

Comment: i have a small image now

Comment: i changed the $myimagepath to the real image, now i have a small rectangle like an image and when i open the source code of the page displayed in my browser. i have this code <img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost:8080/myfirstapp/"> is it normal @Marcel

Comment: Yes, thats just how your image looks like. Maybe at some point you messed up the image with ```gd``` and now it doesn't look like what you expect it to anymore.

Comment: Thank you @Marcel. Enjoy your day