# My PHP cannot create a true color image

Tags: php, php-gd

I have a script that used to create a true color image.

But after changing of server the new PHP installation does not show the image.

Here is the example: `http://www.europasprak.com/engine/system/utils/printBarImage.php?color=%239999FF&width=3&height=10`

The source code is:

```
<?PHP

require_once("website.php");

$color = LibEnv::getEnvHttpGET("color");
$width = LibEnv::getEnvHttpGET("width");
$height = LibEnv::getEnvHttpGET("height");

$color = urldecode($color);

if ($color && $width > 0 && $height> 0) {
  LibImage::printBarImage($color, $width, $height);
}

  // Print a bar image
  static function printBarImage($color, $width, $height) {
    // Create a blank image
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    if (strlen($color) == 6) {
      $color = "#" . $color;
    }

    $r = intval(substr($color, 1, 2), 16);
    $g = intval(substr($color, 3, 2), 16);
    $b = intval(substr($color, 5, 2), 16);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);

    // Fill up the image background
    imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $color);

    // Header indicating the image type
    header("Content-type:image/jpeg");

    // Create the image in the best jpeg quality
    imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);

    // Destroy the image
    imagedestroy($image);
  }

?>
```

My PHP Version 5.6.20 info has this to say:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.5.2
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 6b
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.50
WBMP Support    enabled
XBM Support enabled
```

UPDATE: I commented out the image output and added an existing external image to debug:

```
//    imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);
$img=imagecreatefromjpeg("http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/faten-hamamas-85th-birthday-4804306106580992-hp2x.jpg");
imagejpeg($img, NULL, 100);
```

And the issue remains the same.

So it is probably not related to my GD setup, but lies with the content type.

I removed any BOM characters:

```
tail --bytes=+4 lib/image.php
tail --bytes=+4 system/utils/printBarImage.php
```

I tried different charsets:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 ... -o ...
```

EDIT: I upgraded my GD library to:

```
GD Support  enabled
GD headers Version  2.2.4
GD library Version  2.2.4
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.7.1
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version unknown
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.6.28
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled
```

Using error_log() I can see that the `$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);` function call creates a Resource id #678 and that the `$color = imagecolorallocate($image, $r, $g, $b);` function call returns a color code 6737049.

This issue remained the same though.

I also tried using another function in place of `imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);` and so I tried first `imagepng($image);` and then `imagegif($image);` but the issue remained the same again.

If I comment out the `header("Content-type:image/jpeg");` then the output looks like: ``` ����JFIF``�� ``` with source code:

```
����JFIF``��<CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 100
��C��C��
��  
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    
���w!1AQaq"2�B����  #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?�@����(��
(��?�
```

My browser of choice is Chrome.

Now, if I open the image in Firefox, it shows this: `The image ... cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`.

EDIT: I added some error reporting and the log had this to show:

```
PHP Parse error:  imagepng(): gd-png error: cannot allocate libpng main struct
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The log remains empty on it.

Comment: Your last sample of code works fine for me with PHP 5.

Comment: The code used to work on a previous install, before I changed server. I think it's an installation or configuration issue. Somehow it cannot create images.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded PHP to 5.6.30 and it solved the issue.